# angularfire2 order by value

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have a list in firebase that looks like so

```
[
  {'wlekcbalwvboqwivba': 'Wed Jan 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'},
  {'s243545dkjvbaskdvbj': 'Thu Feb 8 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'}
  {'ckljwbdlvhbwdvlhwbdv': 'Sat Jan 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'},
  {'s243545dkjvbaskdvbj': 'Sun Jan 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'}
]
```

I get the list like this

```
 getBlackList(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]> {
  this.dates = this.db.list(this.datePath );
  return this.dates;
 }
```

I want to order the list by the date string.

I know orderByChild, but the child here is just the $key.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that **dates** is your object, you can do it like this:

```
this.db.list(this.datePath,
    date => {
      date.orderByChild('date')).valueChanges().subscribe(
          d => {
             // You can apply some JS methods, for example reverse() if you want.
             return this.dates = d;
          }
      )
    }
);
```

Hope that helps! :)